# How to map complex object to simple fields

Tags: json, data-binding, jackson, gson

I have a JSON document similar to the following:

```
{
  "aaa": [
    {
      "value": "ewfwefew"
    }
  ],
  "bbb": [
    {
      "value": "ewfewfe"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to deserialize this into something more clean such as:

```
public class MyEntity{
  private String aaa;
  private String bbb;
}
```

What's the best way to unwrap each array and extract the "value" field on deserialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Tim Mac's response is correct, but you can make it *more elegant* by writing a [custom deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer) for your `MyEntity` class.

It should be something like this:

```
private class MyEntityDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyEntity> {

  public MyEntity deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject rootObj = json.getAsJsonObject();

    String nid = rootObj 
                   .get("nid")
                   .getAsJsonArray()
                   .get(0)
                   .getAsJsonObject()
                   .get("value")
                   .getAsString();

    String uuid = rootObj 
                   .get("uuid")
                   .getAsJsonArray()
                   .get(0)
                   .getAsJsonObject()
                   .get("value")
                   .getAsString();

    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(nid, uuid);

    return entity;
  }
}
```

Then you have to register the `TypeAdapter` with:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyEntity.class, new MyEntityDeserializer()).create();
```

And finally you just have to parse your JSON as usual, with:

```
MyEntity entity = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, MyEntity.class);
```

Gson will automatically use your custom deserializer to parse your JSON into your `MyEntity` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the json that you're getting, you might consider deserializing it the way it is, and then converting it to something more manageable?

```
public class TmpEntity {
    public Value[] nid {get;set;}
    public Value[] uuid {get;set;}
}

public class Value {
    public string value {get;set;}
}


public class MyEntity {
    public string nid {get;set;}
    public string uuid {get;set;}
}

var tmp = ...; //deserialize using javascriptserializer
var converted = tmp.Select(a => new MyEntity() 
{
    nid = a.nid.First().value,
    uuid = a.uuid.First().value
}
```